# How to fire an event that show which file is downloading by DownloadFileAsync

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a list of URL collections for download file from the server.

```
foreach (var category in jsonCollection.Categories)
{
    lblFileName.Text = category.File_name; //Here i want to show a message which file is downloading
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(category.Url), @"G:\\PROJECT\\BCCP\\file_name");
    });
    thread.Start();
}
```

I know DownloadFileCompleted handler will be called after completing every file downloaded. But I need an event that will be fired during file downloading so that I can show a message which file is downloading. Here loop just completes the looping and then DownloadFileAsync completing its task asynchronously.

Comment: Why does `DownloadProgressChanged`not solve your problem.

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks for your comment.  I did not think about that. I am new in C#. So which one better?

Answer (score 1):

Use await keyword. The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to insert a suspension point in the execution of the method until the awaited task completes.

```
await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("download_url"), "location_url_where_do_you_want_to_download");
//Do anything what do you want...
```

Must add async keyword before the function name.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution. Using await keyword, make the function async and using DownloadFileTaskAsync

```
private async void functionName()
{
    foreach (var category in jsonCollection.Categories)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(category.Url), @"G:\\PROJECT\\BCCP\\file_name");
            //await for downloading
            lblFileName.Text = category.File_name;
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```